How to split a continuous hex string into space-delimited hex blocks of 32 tuplets each?
I have a fairly long hex string Buffer.toString("hex") that I want to print to a log file in a block of 32 tuplets each.
So basically going from
e01102020809020300800202020809020208095f520c8066054445472b44739621e0d003040401d21044454946583532463447444a4d010000d3104445472b445333374f53474b32010000d4104445472b44533337474b563033010000d503040401d6104445472b444342324354473031010000d7104445472b44504450535f5f5f5f0106009000
to
e0 11 02 02 08 09 02 03 00 80 02 02 02 08 09 02 02 08 09 5f 52 0c 80 66 05 44 45 47 2b 44 73 96
21 e0 d0 03 04 04 01 d2 10 44 45 49 46 58 35 32 46 34 47 44 4a 4d 01 00 00 d3 10 44 45 47 2b 44
53 33 37 4f 53 47 4b 32 01 00 00 d4 10 44 45 47 2b 44 53 33 37 47 4b 56 30 33 01 00 00 d5 03 04
04 01 d6 10 44 45 47 2b 44 43 42 32 43 54 47 30 31 01 00 00 d7 10 44 45 47 2b 44 50 44 50 53 5f
5f 5f 5f 01 06 00 90 00

I have tried hex.replace(/.{64}/g, "$1\n") to wrap the hex string after 32 tuplets but don't know how to add the spaces between the tuplets now.
I would prefer to do that in one regex, if possible?

You can't really do this in one regex in JavaScript because it doesn't support features like variable length lookbehind (in general), conditional replacement or the \G meta sequence. You can just split the string into chunks of up to 64 characters and then those strings into chunks of up to 2 characters, joining the splits with space and newline:


const hex = 'e01102020809020300800202020809020208095f520c8066054445472b44739621e0d003040401d21044454946583532463447444a4d010000d3104445472b445333374f53474b32010000d4104445472b44533337474b563033010000d503040401d6104445472b444342324354473031010000d7104445472b44504450535f5f5f5f0106009000'

const out = hex
    .match(/(.{1,64})/g)
    .map(s => s.match(/.{1,2}/g).join(' '))
    .join('\n')

console.log(out)



Note I've used {1,2} in the second regex in case your data might have an odd number of characters. If it won't, you can simply use .{2} (or simplify to just ..).
You could also define a replacer function to split the string using one regex into variable line lengths:


const replacer = n => {
  let cnt = 0
  return (m) => m + ((++cnt % n) ? ' ' : '\n')
}

const hex = 'e01102020809020300800202020809020208095f520c8066054445472b44739621e0d003040401d21044454946583532463447444a4d010000d3104445472b445333374f53474b32010000d4104445472b44533337474b563033010000d503040401d6104445472b444342324354473031010000d7104445472b44504450535f5f5f5f0106009000'

let out = hex.replace(/../g, replacer(32))

console.log(out)

out = hex.replace(/../g, replacer(16))

console.log(out)

out = hex.replace(/../g, replacer(8))

console.log(out)



Out of interest, I ran 1000 iterations of each answer on my computer with a 3000 character input string. The results (in milliseconds) were:



algorithm
result




Nick (match/join)
1208


blhsing
1300


Oussama BASRY
1362


Pointy
2092


Nick (replacer)
2142



So although the replacer functions give great flexibility, it comes at a performance cost because of all the function calls.

I was working on a way to do it with a single .replace(/xyz/g, (_, pair) ... ) call, which I think is possible but I got bored.

@Pointy I had a similar idea using a closure - see my edit

yea same idea. That feature of .replace() is one of my favorite things.

replace is magic! Didn't think of that, thanks Pointy and Nick!
I think I like this the best.
For heavy logging it would interesting to see which of the methods is the fastest. Can performance tests be done here on SO?

The replacer method seems to add an additional \n at the end, when the number of tuplets on the last line align with n. At least in my code, I can't seem to see the newline in the example code output for the replace(8) case.

I'm not sure trying to run performance tests on SO would be very useful, as you'd be potentially adding web traffic into the results. I did run tests on my computer though, see my edit

@philk I'm only seeing a single newline at the end of the last line

That's cool Nick, thanks. I wonder if a hybrid, with a replacer that matches between 1 and 32 pairs, and then splits that up in a for loop in the callback, would compare better or worse.

@Pointy I tried a simple for-loop with substring, but it was still about 50% slower than my simple match/join

Yea I'm not surprised, I didn't really think it'd be faster. Honestly it's been a long time since I've really worried about "speed" in normal web applications. (I don't do games, so maybe that's a thing.)

@Pointy yeah, even the slowest code takes 2ms for one iteration, so unlikely to bother anyone for speed.

You could also do your looping inside the regex engine:


const src = 'e01102020809020300800202020809020208095f520c8066054445472b44739621e0d003040401d21044454946583532463447444a4d010000d3104445472b445333374f53474b32010000d4104445472b44533337474b563033010000d503040401d6104445472b444342324354473031010000d7104445472b44504450535f5f5f5f0106009000';

function format(src) {
  let bytes = 0;
  return src.replace(/../g, byte => {
    if (bytes === 31) {
      bytes = 0;
      return `${byte}\n`;
    }
    bytes++;
    return `${byte} `;
  });
}

console.log(format(src));



(That could probably be code-golfed down a little, but I wanted to be clear.)
That uses the feature of the string .replace() method, which allows a function to be passed as the second argument. The format() function keeps a counter and resets it on newlines.
The regular expression matching will be done over and over, but that regex will simply "eat" two characters on each iteration and then invoke the callback each time. It's not re-scanning the entire source string. The return string is built inside the regex engine from the values returned by the callback.

this is basically the replacer technique that @Nick also proposed in his answer. I like it very much!

@philk to be fair, Pointy gave this answer first, I just made a different version of it afterwards.

FYI, out of interest, I ran performance tests on my computer of all the proposed answers. I have added the results to the end of my answer.

You can use \B to assert a non-word boundary after a tuplet to insert spaces only between tuplets:


const hex = 'e01102020809020300800202020809020208095f520c8066054445472b44739621e0d003040401d21044454946583532463447444a4d010000d3104445472b445333374f53474b32010000d4104445472b44533337474b563033010000d503040401d6104445472b444342324354473031010000d7104445472b44504450535f5f5f5f0106009000';
console.log(hex.replace(/.{64}/g, '$&\n').replace(/..\B/g, '$& '))




This is nice and simple

FYI, out of interest, I ran performance tests on my computer of all the proposed answers. I have added the results to the end of my answer.
